# R: loop through variable names in data.table using for-loop (and group them by variable)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, data.table

```
> colnames(fileIWantToAnalyze) 

[1] "variable_1a"     "variable_5b"                                  
[3] "variable_1b"     "variable_6a"                           
[5] "variable_2a"     "variable_6b"                           
[7] "variable_2b"     "variable_7a"                           
[9] "variable_3a"     "variable_7b"                           
[11] "variable_3b"    "variable_8a"        
[13] "variable_4a"    "variable_8b"       
[15] "variable_4b"    "variable_9a"            
[17] "variable_5a"    "variable_9b"            
[19] "GroupingColumn1"
```

I am not able to run the following code in R - throws this error:

> Error in [.data.table(fileIWantToAnalyze, , .(mean1 = mean(get(attribute)),  : The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (943026,1). Each must be length 943026; the same length as there are rows in x (after subsetting if i is provided).

"fileIWantToAnalyze" is a data.table

```
for(attribute in colnames(fileIWantToAnalyze)[c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17)]){
  fileIWantToAnalyze[,.(mean1 = mean(get(attribute)),count1 = .N),
                      by = .(GroupingColumn1,sub("a", "b", attribute))]
}
```

This doesn't work too

```
for (attribute in colnames(fileIWantToAnalyze)[c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17)]){
  fileIWantToAnalyze[,.(mean1 = mean(get(attribute)),count1 = .N),
    by = .(GroupingColumn1,attribute)]
}
```

The following code gives me the answer I am looking for - but I want to use a loop to generate outputs for many variables

```
fileIWantToAnalyze[,.(mean1 = mean(variable_1a),count1 = .N),
    by = .(GroupingColumn1,variable_1b))]
```

I believe the problem is how I am calling the the "attribute" in the 'by' command while grouping

Comment: Telling us what doesn't work while not telling what the goal is   ... well, you should be able to understand our problem in understanding your problem. ..... Not to mention that fact that this does not have a [MCVE] making this a not very attractive problem to spend any time on. Sorry. Look at [ask], and [MCVE] and [edit].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is from the fact of how variables are interpreted by the the `data.table` function, although this might actually be an unintended bug.

Note the following dummy example to illustrate:

```
dt <- data.table(A = 1:3, b = 3:5, c = 7:5)
#Works:
for(i in names(dt))
  dt[,lapply(.SD, sum), by = i]
#doesnt work
for(i in names(dt))
  dt[,lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(i)]
#works
for(i in names(dt))
  dt[,lapply(.SD, sum), by = c(i)]
```

Basically it seems `data.table` doesn't check if each element of `.(...)` is a single character vector contained in the namespace of the table.

So an easy fix is to just use a character vector in the `by` argument instead. Below is a revisited version of your code.

```
for(attribute in colnames(fileIWantToAnalyze)[seq(1, 17, by = 2]){
  fileIWantToAnalyze[,.(mean1 = mean(get(attribute)),count1 = .N),
                      #Note that "by" is now in a character vector.  
                      by = c("GroupingColumn1", sub("a", "b", attribute))]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider reshaping your wide data to long format, usually the preferred method of most analytical methods (aggregating, plotting, modeling). With such an approach, you avoid complex looping. Plus, data.table has [reshaping methods](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html) including `melt` and `dcast`.

```
melt_dt <- melt(fileIWantToAnalyze, 
                id.vars = c("GroupingColumn1"), 
                measure.vars = list(paste0("variable_", 1:9, "a"),
                                    paste0("variable_", 1:9, "b"))
                value.name = c("value_a", "value_b")
               )

agg_dt <- melt_dt[, .(mean_value=(value_a), count=.N), 
                  by=list(GroupingColumn1, value_b)][order(GroupingColumn1, value_b)]
```